# Rust: How to specify lifetimes in closure arguments?

Tags: debugging, iterator, closures, rust, lifetime

I'm writing a parser generator as a project to learn rust, and I'm running into something I can't figure out with lifetimes and closures. Here's my simplified case (sorry it's as complex as it is, but I need to have the custom iterator in the real version and it seems to make a difference in the compiler's behavior):

Playpen link: http://is.gd/rRm2aa

```
struct MyIter<'stat, T:Iterator<&'stat str>>{
    source: T
}

impl<'stat, T:Iterator<&'stat str>> Iterator<&'stat str> for MyIter<'stat, T>{
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'stat str>{
        self.source.next()
    }
}

struct Scanner<'stat,T:Iterator<&'stat str>>{
    input: T
}

impl<'main> Scanner<'main, MyIter<'main,::std::str::Graphemes<'main>>>{
    fn scan_literal(&'main mut self) -> Option<String>{
        let mut token = String::from_str("");
        fn get_chunk<'scan_literal,'main>(result:&'scan_literal mut String, 
                                          input: &'main mut MyIter<'main,::std::str::Graphemes<'main>>) 
         -> Option<&'scan_literal mut String>{
            Some(input.take_while(|&chr| chr != "\"")
                 .fold(result, |&mut acc, chr|{
                     acc.push_str(chr);
                     &mut acc
                 }))
        }
        get_chunk(&mut token,&mut self.input);
        println!("token is {}", token);
        Some(token)
    }
}

fn main(){
    let mut scanner = Scanner{input:MyIter{source:"\"foo\"".graphemes(true)}};
    scanner.scan_literal();
}
```

There are two problems I know of here. First, I have to shadow the 'main lifetime in the get_chunk function (I tried using the one in the `impl`, but the compiler complains that `'main` is undefined inside `get_chunk`). I think it will still work out because the call to get_chunk later will match the `'main` from the `impl` with the `'main` from `get_chunk`, but I'm not sure that's right.

The second problem is that the `&mut acc` inside the closure needs to have a lifetime of `'scan_literal` in order to work like I want it to (accumulating characters until the first `"` is encountered for this example). I can't add an explicit lifetime to `&mut acc` though, and the compiler says its lifetime is limited to the closure itself, and thus I can't return the reference to use in the next iteration of fold. I've gotten the function to compile and run in various other ways, but I don't understand what the problem is here.

My main question is: Is there any way to explicitly specify the lifetime of an argument to a closure? If not, is there a better way to accumulate the string using fold without doing multiple copies?

Comment: It now occured to me that you think that lifetime parameters are named after functions; this is not so. Lifetime parameters have arbitrary names and in fact they have nothing to do with functions. You also can't specify a lifetime parameter manually when you're calling a function which needs one. The compiler will do it automatically.

Comment: Actually the lifetime names I have in there are an artifact of debugging, trying to trace where things are instantiated and what the corresponding scopes are. They may not be correct, but that's what's going on there. I realize that the names don't have any particular meaning as far as the compiler is concerned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, about lifetimes. Functions defined inside other functions are static, they are not connected with their outside code in any way. Consequently, their lifetime parameters are completely independent. You don't want to use `'main` as a lifetime parameter for `get_chunk()` because it will shadow the outer `'main` lifetime and give nothing but confusion.

Next, about closures. This expression:

```
|&mut acc, chr| ...
```

very likely does not what you really think it does. Closure/function arguments allow irrefutable patterns in them, and `&` have special meaning in patterns. Namely, it dereferences the value it is matched against, and assigns its identifier to this dereferenced value:

```
let x: int = 10i;
let p: &int = &x;
match p {
    &y => println!("{}", y)  // prints 10
}
```

You can think of `&` in a pattern as an opposite to `&` in an expression: in an expression it means "take a reference", in a pattern it means "remove the reference".

`mut`, however, does not belong to `&` in patterns; it belongs to the identifier and means that the variable with this identifier is mutable, i.e. you should write not

```
|&mut acc, chr| ...
```

but

```
|& mut acc, chr| ...
```

You may be interested in [this RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/179) which is exactly about this quirk in the language syntax.

It looks like that you want to do a very strange thing, I'm not sure I understand where you're getting at. It is very likely that you are confusing different string kinds. First of all, you should read [the official guide](http://doc.rust-lang.org/guide.html) which explains ownership and borrowing and when to use them (you may also want to read the [unfinished ownership guide](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/18613); it will soon get into the main documentation tree), and then you should read [strings guide](http://doc.rust-lang.org/guide-strings.html).

Anyway, your problem can be solved in much simpler and generic way:

```
#[deriving(Clone)]
struct MyIter<'s, T: Iterator<&'s str>> {
    source: T
}

impl<'s, T: Iterator<&'s str>> Iterator<&'s str> for MyIter<'s, T>{
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'s str>{ // '
        self.source.next()
    }
}

#[deriving(Clone)]
struct Scanner<'s, T: Iterator<&'s str>> {
    input: T
} 

impl<'m, T: Iterator<&'m str>> Scanner<'m, T> {  // '
    fn scan_literal(&mut self) -> Option<String>{
        fn get_chunk<'a, T: Iterator<&'a str>>(input: T) -> Option<String> {
            Some(
                input.take_while(|&chr| chr != "\"")
                     .fold(String::new(), |mut acc, chr| {
                         acc.push_str(chr);
                         acc
                     })
            )
        }
        let token = get_chunk(self.input.by_ref());
        println!("token is {}", token);
        token
    }
}

fn main(){
    let mut scanner = Scanner{
        input: MyIter {
            source: "\"foo\"".graphemes(true)
        }
    };
    scanner.scan_literal();
}
```

You don't need to pass external references into the closure; you can generate a `String` directly in `fold()` operation. I also generified your code and made it more idiomatic.

Note that now `impl` for `Scanner` also works with arbitrary iterators returning `&str`. It is very likely that you want to write this instead of specializing `Scanner` to work only with `MyIter` with `Graphemes` inside it. `by_ref()` operation turns `&mut I` where `I` is an `Iterator<T>` into `J`, where `J` is an `Iterator<T>`. It allows further chaining of iterators even if you only have a mutable reference to the original iterator.

By the way, your code is also incomplete; it will only return `Some("")` because the `take_while()` will stop at the first quote and won't scan further. You should rewrite it to take initial quote into account.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer. This particular piece of code is a simplified version of the actual code, which does take the initial quote into account as well as supporting escaped characters with the backslash syntax.

Comment: The middle of my comment disappeared when I submitted for some reason, sorry about that. I had meant to ask about the copying behavior of your solution - is the accumulator in fold copied at each iteration, or is there some kind of optimization happening to prevent that? The original reason for the reference was to avoid having the whole string copied each time a character is added.

Comment: @Erik: No, the accumulator is not copied, it's moved. `push_str` mutates the `String` in place.

Comment: @Erik, Rust is made in a way when nothing expensive happens implicitly. You have to opt-in for the most expensive things, including copying. Rust copies automatically only `Copy` types; values of other types are always moved. `String` is not `Copy`, so in this case it is repeatedly moved in and out of the closure. It does involve copying the bytes which make up `String` structure (a pointer, a length and a capacity), but it does not mean that the whole `String` buffer will be copied.

Comment: Excellent, that's something I hadn't picked up on from the guide, but it makes sense. Thanks for your help.